How to Create Detailed Stitches Similar to This?
I'm working on replicating a specific type of stitch pattern and texture for a project, and I need some guidance. I've attached a close-up image of the stitch I'm trying to recreate
I've already searched YouTube and done some research, but I couldn't find anything that matches this style.
Could anyone provide insights on:
The type of stitching technique used here?
The tools and materials I might need to replicate this?
Any tutorials or resources to help me create something similar?


Hello, do you need to model it? Because you could simply create a bump map from your current picture

I have tried that too but it wont be satisfied the client so i need a different approach.

what about the rest of the tissue? Do you just need a stitch on a flat surface? I guess you can model it with some kind of cylinders that you bend?

i need only stiches the other tissue has been made in procedural texuring and baking. the only thing remain is stitch.

Yeah, I'm of the opinion that you should just model it out. Literally take a curve and "sew" the cloth together by manually weaving it through, adjusting the curve radius etc. Any attempt to do it fancy or procedurally would take alot longer than just doing it the "slow way" which would probably take about 15 minutes at most.
